# Formatting Numpy to CSV output for arrays with string and float

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy

So,

I'm very new to Python so I've likely not understood something straightforward.

I'm testing (playing with) a small barometric sensor on a Raspberry Pi. The sensor outputs values for pressure and temperature, as well as some other things that are unimportant.

I have written a small program that stores input for both pressure and temperature and places it into a numpy array. Then using numpy.savetxt I output to a csv file for reading with a generic spreadsheet application later on.

To be useful I also need to timestamp each output, i.e. "sometemperature", "somepressure", "current date and time" in the csv file.

I'm struggling with the format option of numpy since my array contains two floats and a string. I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temppressurelogger.py", line 15, in <module>
    np.savetxt("output.csv", data.reshape((1,3)), fmt = "%.2f %.2f %s", delimiter=",")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1073, in savetxt
    fh.write(asbytes(format % tuple(row) + newline))
TypeError: float argument required, not numpy.string_
```

I've been trying to figure out exactly how to give a correct fmt option but an hour or so of googling hasn't really located anything concerning both strings and floats in the same array in the same row.

Based on some feedback earlier I have written the program below with hard coded values for testing so that the Adafruit libraries are not required. My current simple program is:

```
    # import Adafruit_BMP.BMP085 as BMP085 # Using the Adafruit BMP sensor library
import time
import numpy as np

# sensor = BMP085.BMP085() # Defines sensor from which to read

t = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time())) # Stores local time in t
temperature = 18.01 #sensor.read_temperature()
pressure = 10080.79 #sensor.read_pressure()

data = np.array([[temperature], [pressure], [t]])
np.dtype([("temperature", float), ("pressure", float), ("t", "S20")])
#print(array.shape)

np.savetxt("output.csv", data.reshape((1,3)), fmt = "%.2f %.2f %s", delimiter=",")
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Write your example code in a way that does not require us to have Adafruit.  Just put hard-coded numbers in.

Comment: Okay rewritten with some hard-coded numbers and no requirement for the Adafruit module.